# Check for timestamp conflict in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I want to check for a date and time conflict using mysql and php.

My timestamp is formated using php code such as:

```
$timestamp_start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H", strtotime($start_time)), date("i", strtotime($start_time)), 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]));
$timestamp_end = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H", strtotime($end_time)), date("i", strtotime($end_time)), 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]));
```

And I do mysql check like this below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$info[table]` WHERE ((`timestamp_start` BETWEEN '$timestamp_start' AND '$timestamp_end') OR (`timestamp_end` BETWEEN '$timestamp_start' AND '$timestamp_end'))";
```

Which is code I got from here! haha.

Now the issue is that if the room is scheduled for 10/31/2013 from 08:00 AM to 05:00 PM and someone else tries to schedule it for 10/31/2013 from 5:00 PM to 09:00 PM they get a message stating that the room is already in use. Now I didnt mind this at first because than it forced the room to have atleast a 30 minute gap between events, but my bosses said that the room should be able to be scheduled back to back.

How can I modify my sql statement to allow someone to request the room at 05:00 PM if it is booked all the way to 05:00 PM?

This seems to work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$info[table]` WHERE `approved`='true' AND (`timestamp_start` < '$timestamp_end' AND `timestamp_end` > '$timestamp_start')";
```

Comment: instead of using between, you could use < and >

Comment: Why aren't you just doing the date formatting in the query?

Comment: I have no answer for this... I just did it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive operation, e.g.

```
 foo BETWEEN bar AND baz
```

is the equivalent of

```
 (foo >= bar) AND (foo <= baz)
```

Since you want to allow "overlap" on the cutoff times, you'll have to ditch the `BETWEEN operation, and go for the more tedious-to-write-out

```
 (foo >= bar) AND (foo < baz)
                       ^--- non-inclusive
```

Comment: So I adjusted my `$sql` to look like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM info[table] WHERE ((timestamp_start>='$timestamp_start' AND timestamp_start<'$timestamp_end') OR (timestamp_end > '$timestamp_start' AND timestamp_end <= '$timestamp_end'))";` but am getting an error `unexpected <`

Comment: is a php unexpected, or mysql unexpected?

Comment: I am not sure but the actual error accrues when I try to free the mysqli query. `Call to a member function free() on a non-object in <b>URL-REMOVED</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 0):

Found this on  another question asked here:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$info[table]` WHERE `approved`='true' AND (`timestamp_start` < '$timestamp_end' AND `timestamp_end` > '$timestamp_start')";
```

And it appears to be working using the limited testing I did.